# Rounding column in Adempiere

Tags: adempiere

I am using Adempiere and there's a Grand Total column in window Purchase Order

[image]

I want the amount to be rounded above, so `Grand Total` will show `42,432,001`

I've tried changing Price Precision but it still doesn't work.

How can I change it ?

Answer (score 0):

As its name implies the Pricing Precision would only apply rounding when *generating* prices on a pricelist.  You might read [this](http://wiki.adempiere.net/Rounding) page from the adempiere wiki on the topic of rounding in documents and in particular you might also want to read its [discussion](http://wiki.adempiere.net/Talk:Rounding) page.  To my knowledge this functionality has not been implemented so it will require some coding but as you see from the discussion it has some potential to be a complex (in legal & accounting terms) than would initially suspected.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, it's by modifying column in the database.

I use Oracle 12c, and the column is `GrandTotal`. I use `ROUND()` function

all I do is updating the column.

```
UPDATE C_ORDERLINE SET GRANDTOTAL = ROUND(GRANDTOTAL)
```

It works.

Comment: this will not be the perfect solution as you have to run this statement every time you enter a new line.

Comment: plus the calculation re accounting & tax will not add up